# Html.ValidationmMessage does not show message error on client of WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, validation

When I create a Asp.net Web client to test the WCF service, the model class on the WCF service:

```
public partial class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And the Create View generated by Scaffold in Client is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the @html.ValidationMessageFor only show the message for Id, Price and Quantity. It does not work with the ProductName Field. And the render code html is:

```
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." 
          data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="number" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ProductName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The input tag of ProductName field not include data-val, data-val-required like id, price and quantity. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: So the model comes from a wcf service? Attributes are, as far as I know, not serialized. The reason that you see messages for the integers is because they are automatically implemented by the helper, because the are not-nullable.

Comment: Thank ! Do you know any solution to maintain the validation on client ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I am having the same issue with validation.